# subtracting two integer that are represented in an array

Tags: java, arrays, subtraction

I am trying to subtract two numbers that get put into an array (Im subtracting to numbers like 532 and 67)

so effectively this is what the array looks like

```
list a

index: 2 1 0

list:  5 3 2  <-- this is the first number

~~~~~~~~

list b

index: 1 0

list: 6 7  <-- this is the second number

~~~~~~~~~~
```

the trouble I'm having is implementing a way so that you can borrow from the next number over.

My idea was something like `a[i+1]-1` to get the 3 to lower to a 2
and add `a[i]+10` so that I can subtract in the ones place, and so on

any tips/help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: this is from a homework assignment, and I dont want to appear to ask you guys for answers :p

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you, even if you don't ask.

Comment: just asking for ideas on how to tackle it

Comment: How would you tackle it in real life? Lets say i gave you 3 numbers - eg:  7, 5 and 3 . And I ask you to make 753 number from it. How you will use maths to make 753 out of this 3 numbers?

Comment: @vikiiii well i would take 7*100 + 5*10 + 3*1

Comment: @JAVA_man Are you supposed to use the carry over subtraction on the array, or can you also convert the array to a number and subtract from it?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder the subtraction should carry over on the array so when im taking 7 from 2, i cant do that, so i have to decrement the value of 3, the next element over, and increase the 2 to a twelve, except i dont know how to translate that into java

Comment: question, can i put a link to a real time java collab website here, better I ask than break rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think it will solve your problem and return your result. Also let me know this is working for you or not.

```
package test;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstNumber[]={1,9};
    int secondNumber[]={8,0,8,9};
    int result[];

    boolean isNegativeResult =false;
    Test test =new Test();

    isNegativeResult=!test.isFirstGreater(firstNumber,secondNumber);

    if(isNegativeResult){
        result=test.subtract(secondNumber,firstNumber);
    }else{
        result=test.subtract(firstNumber,secondNumber);
    }
    System.out.print(isNegativeResult?"- ":"");
    for(int index=result.length-1;index>=0;index--){
        System.out.print(result[index]);
    }

}
public int[] subtract(int[] firstNumber,int[] secondNumber){
    int result[]=new int[firstNumber.length];
    for(int index=0;index<firstNumber.length;index++){
        if(index>secondNumber.length-1){
            result[index]=firstNumber[index];
            continue;
        }
        if(firstNumber[index]<secondNumber[index]){
            for(int j=index+1;j<firstNumber.length;j++){
                if(firstNumber[j]!=0){
                    firstNumber[j]=firstNumber[j]-1;
                    firstNumber[index]+=10;
                    break;
                }else{
                    firstNumber[j]=9;
                }
            }
        }
        result[index]=firstNumber[index]-secondNumber[index];
    }
    return result;
}
public boolean isFirstGreater(int[] first,int[] second){
    boolean result=true;
    if(first.length<second.length){
        result= false;
        for(int index=second.length-1;index>=0;index--){
            if(second[index]>0){
                break;
            }else{
                if(index==(first.length-1) && first[index]<second[index]){
                    result= false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }else if(first.length==second.length){
        for(int index=first.length-1;index>=0;index--){
            if(first[index]<second[index]){
                result= false;
                break;
            }else if(first[index]>second[index]){
                result= true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method would probably work, but it might be a bit complicated because you are going to have to keep checking whether or not you need to borrow from the next number over. And what about the case of 1001 - 99, you are going to have to borrow a bunch of times, and not just from one place over.

Do you have to keep the values in individual array indices for this assignment? Why not create integer numbers from the array and subtract them normally.

For example, if I have what you say:

```
a[0] = 2
a[1] = 3
a[2] = 5
```

and this is supposed to be the number 532, why not construct some other int a = 532, then use that with a simple a - b?

How would we construct the int a? Well consider what the numbers are telling you, they are telling you the value of each of the digits, first the ones, tens, hundreds, etc. Consider these alternative ways to write 532:

```
532 = 500 + 30 + 2
532 = 5*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 2*10^0
```

See if that helps!